# How to record page loading time by click the link in page

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I'm looking for a way to record page switching/loading time by clicking the hyperlink in another page, in chrome only

So lets say, I have added page B's hyperlink in page A, now I want to know how many seconds it takes from clicking the hyperlink to finishing loading page A.

I'm playing around development tool - performance tab but looks like it will not record the time across different tabs/ windows.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the link is the same as accessing that page directly through the browser, so you can use Google Chrome's "Performance" section in the Developer Tools and use the "Start profiling and reload the page" option when you're on the page you want to profile.

[image]